# .htaccess won't rewrite my url at all

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been crawling forums for about 2 hours and still haven't found the solution to my problem so I am turning to you guys for help.

My URL looks like this
 
http://gymbirdz.com/article.php?url=benefits-of-fish-oil
 
I want it to look like this
 
http://gymbirdz.com/article/benefits-of-fish-oil

This is my .htaccess request but It does not work and still no luck fixing it :/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?article/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /article.php?url=$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Any help is appreciated very much!  Thank You

**UPDATE**
This is how my .htaccess looks from above

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^article/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)$ article.php?url=$1 [NC,R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.gymbirdz\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/gymbirdz\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^192\.254\.185\.208
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.gymbirdz.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule your site root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.gymbirdz\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^192\.254\.185\.208$
RewriteRule (.*) http://gymbirdz.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]            

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /article\.php\?url=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /article/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^/?article/([\w-]+)/?$ article.php?url=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but still not luck :/ My Rewrites for index.php (deleting it from url) and also deleting the "www" from url works, but this portion is not working and it really drives me crazy.

Comment: @user3316749 - what URL are you testing with in your browser? And did you place the rules shown in this answer *above* your index.php rewrite?

Comment: Also, you need to add a `<base href="/">` tag to your `<head>`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for getting back to me. I updated my question - please take a look above again. But in short, yest the CODE is above all the other rewrites and I just put the <base href="/"> code to my head tag but still no luck.

Comment: Somehow the bottom URL works and redirects to the TOP url (url are mentioned above) but it is not what I am looking for. It should be revered. The top URL should display a s the second one.

Comment: I've provided full .htaccess in my answer now. Replace your code with this and make sure to clear your browser cache before testing it.

Comment: Thank you very much it works!! I am sad cause I do not understand why :( but it works! Strange though, cause all tutorials online for URL rewriting were in one simple sentence like ` ^articles$ articles.php ` and yet it does not work on my side.

Comment: It works due to disabling `MultiViews` option and keeping `article` rule at the bottom.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I don't understand your question, but this is from the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> Syntax:   RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]

This is your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?article/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /article.php?url=$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

It appears that you may have the two arguments reversed. Try something like this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^article.php?url=([\w-]+) /article/$1 [NC,L,R=301,QSA]
```

This assumes that the `.htaccess` file is in the same directory as `article.php`.

Comment: No, this is incorrect. The *Pattern* never starts with a slash (only does in server config context), and query strings are *not* part of the request URI. Please read the documentation before posting answers, Josh.

Comment: Updated due to using this in an .htaccess file.

Comment: Still, there is the issue of the query string in the Pattern, which is not valid. Query strings may only be checked by `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ...`.